# Raspberry pi serial port data wrong

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi, processing

I connected an Arduino Board to Raspberry through an USB port. With a Processing code i want to read 70 bytes sended by arduino. If i use this program on my PC windows it works, but with Raspberry the data that i get from Processing are different from the data sended by arduino. This is the Processing code to read the serial port:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial uart;
byte[] codice= new byte[70];

void setup() {
  uart= new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (uart.available()>0) {
    codice=uart.readBytes();
    println(codice);
  }
}
```

In my case the serial port is "dev/ttyUSB0". I tried also with python in this way:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
>>> while True:
 ...     print ser.readline()
```

Also in python there is the same error. I also tried to change the baud rate (115200) with the same result.

Comment: @marc For example I should have values between 20 and 22, but on raspberry I have values between 10 and 40

Comment: what does the data you sent look like (the 70 bytes)?

Comment: @george 65 bytes com from a sensor called Grid eye infrared sensor [link](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/sensors/sensors-automotive-industrial-applications/grid-eye-infrared-array-sensor), and they are tmperature maesures, while the other 5 bytes come from other sensors

Comment: Does the output look different if you read one byte at a time ? What byte are you using to terminate the packet send from Arduino ?

Answer (score 0):

Unplug your Arduino, search with `ls /dev/tty*` and plug it in. 
If you now search again with `ls /dev/tty*` you will see a new device, for example `/dev/ttyACM0`. Additionally you need the arduino drivers to emulate the COM-Port `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino`. 
Arduino Code

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(“Hello Raspi”);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Raspberry Pi Code-Snippet

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

Try the python example on this page: [How to attach an Arduino?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino)

Comment: Thank you for the answer the only device that i find is  `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The system is updated and also arduino is the newest version

Comment: I found a reference to /dev/ttyUSB0, that is the device name for example FT232RL chips. The device reference is ok.